# .Net Core Worker Service should only run when Windows Service is turned on

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-service-worker

I created worker service class in my web api project and then setup to run as Windows Service by modifying the program.cs by adding .UseWindowsSerivce(). Then I published my api to app server. I have disabled my windows service which triggers this worker service class, but still the code inside the worker service class is invoked with my windows service in that web server is disabled. Can someone tell me why it would work that way? or tell me how to invoke that worker service class only if windows service is enabled and running otherwise it should not call the workerservice.cs

Comment: *I created worker service class in my web api project and then setup to run as Windows Service*... Why? Why would you do this? Why wouldn't you just run the `IHostedService` inside your WebAPI, or compile two separate projects: One as a WebAPI and the other as a Windows Service.

Comment: I like the second one and it worked for me. Can you elaborate on implementing the first one?